# Cannot store my data into table with specific column

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert data into the table from specific column in my form submission. I've already insured that there is connection with the database. I would like to know if I am doing this properly. Here is my code:

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db_elcventory");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql1 = "UPDATE request_items_db (req_qty) VALUES ('$amount1') WHERE item_db.item_id= request_items_db.item_id ";

if (mysqli_query($link, $sql1)){
    //$exec = mysqli_query($link, $sql1);
    echo "Records added successfully";                                
}
else {
    echo "ERROR: Could not execute.".mysqli_error($link);
}

mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

---

> ERROR: Could not execute.You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(req_qty) VALUES ('2') WHERE item_db.item_id= request_items_db.item_id' at line 1

Below is the Layout of my form:

The Form Consist of the Item ID, Item name and Amount. The `item_ID` and the `item_name` is from the `item_db`, but the amount is need to store in the `req_qty` where the `item_id` is same with the `item_id` in the `item_db`.

[image]

Comment: INSERT/UPDATE which one works with WHERE clause...?

Answer (score 0):

You've missed a `'` after `$amout1`. Your query should look like this

```
INSERT INTO request_items_db (req_qty) VALUES ('$amount1')
```

`WHERE` may be used in `INSERT INTO SELECT`, `UPDATE` OR `DELETE` statements but not in your's which is a simple `INSERT`

### UPDATE

The update query you are trying is not correct

```
UPDATE request_items_db (req_qty) VALUES ('$amount1') WHERE item_db.item_id= request_items_db.item_id
```

should be

```
UPDATE request_items_db SET req_qty = '$amount1' WHERE request_items_db.item_id = '$item_id'
```

Comment: Just insert the missing ' into the query..

can u suggest the statement?? Thanks, coz I still new in php coding

Comment: @AddisonLee, update query should be like this `UPDATE request_items_db SET req_qty = '$amount1') WHERE  request_items_db.item_id=<value>`. You have to provide the <value>

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If the value is the item_id. How can I provide the value? Coz I have different item_id for different item, and the item_id will increase. Based on the admin to key in the item name and the item_id will auto increase.

Comment: @AddisonLee, do you mean `item01` is the value in the table? if yes then use `UPDATE request_items_db SET req_qty = '$amount1') WHERE request_items_db.item_id='item01'`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If the value is the item_id. How can I provide the value? Coz I have different item_id for different item, and the item_id will increase. Based on the admin to key in the item name and the item_id will auto increase.

Comment: @AddisonLee, you'll have to pass the `item_id` too from the form along with  `amount1`, so you'll get two values, one `$amount1` and the other `$item_id`. `$amount1` will be saved against `$item_id`. Your query will look like `"UPDATE request_items_db SET req_qty = '$amount1' WHERE request_items_db.item_id='$item_id'`

Comment: Thanks.. meanwhile I can update my query. But I got another issue is if I got 2 different item_id with 2 different req_qty with only one $amount1 than only will update my 2nd req_qty, but my first item_id will not update the req_qty?

Answer (score 0):

First, your syntax is incorrect. It should be

```
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO request_items_db (req_qty) VALUES ('$amount1') 
         WHERE item_db.item_id= request_items_db.item_id ";
```

Second, you can't use `WHERE` with `INSERT`. If you want to update already existing field, then use `UPDATE` query. Your `UPDATE` query should be

```
$sql1 = "UPDATE request_items_db SET req_qty='$amount1' 
          WHERE  item_db.item_id= request_items_db.item_id";
```

Comment: I just change the query into UPDATE but still counter error.. Please advise.. Thanks alot

Comment: Sorry to ask.. If I want to jus update my req_qty in the request_item_db=item_db? 

Can the code like this:
$sql1 = "UPDATE request_items_db SET req_qty='$amount1' WHERE request_items_db.item_id";

Comment: You will to give the proper condition like this `$sql1 = "UPDATE request_items_db SET req_qty='$amount1' WHERE request_items_db.item_id = 'value'";`. `value` is the value of where you want to update the data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If the value is the item_id. How can I provide the value? Coz I have different item_id for different item, and the item_id will increase. Based on the admin to key in the item name and the item_id will auto increase.